# convert mmm dd, yyyy, h:mm am in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

An application exports with a text field that combines date and time in the format shown below. This format is a bit different (there's a comma after the year for starters) than the answer to "convert MMM DD, YYYY HH:MM:SS am in Excel" which was answered on Stackflow on 6/2/2014. I tried running the VBA code that the answer provided but am getting a run time error 13 and type mismatch.  I don't know enough about VBA to know what changes I should make to the VBA code.  Any help would be gratefully received.

```
Apr 5, 2018, 10:00 AM
Apr 15, 2018, 2:00 PM 
Apr 30, 2018, 7:00 PM
```

Comment: Please post your code using code tags so we can see it.

Comment: What are you converting it to?

Answer (score 1):

### **Formulas and some background:**

If you are trying to get a date have a look at a couple of ideas using formulas that will aid your understanding with using VBA later. Ultimately you need to create a string that can be parsed as a date. In the example you quoted the `CDate` function was able to recognise the string as a date and convert it to Date datatype.

1) With yours, if `Apr 5, 2018, 10:00 AM` were in `A2`, you could use a simple:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(", ",A2,FIND(", ",A2)+1)-1),",",""),4),MONTH(1&LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(", ",A2,FIND(", ",A2)+1)-1),",",""),3)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(", ",A2,FIND(", ",A2)+1)-1),",",""),5,2)))
```

The inner

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(", ",A2,FIND(", ",A2)+1)-1),",","")
```

gets the string before second "," , then replaces the remaining "," with "" giving

```
Apr 5 2018
```

The rest of the formula uses the `Date` function to create a date from the dateparts i.e. Year,Month,Day.

There are assumptions made that Month will be always 3 letter abbreviation. Single white spaces inside the string and no additional white space either side.

2) Without such assumptions you may end up with something like:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),CHAR(32),CHAR(1),3))-1),4),MONTH(1&LEFT(LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),CHAR(32),CHAR(1),3))-1),3)),MID(A4,4,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),CHAR(32),CHAR(1),3))-1),CHAR(32),CHAR(1),2))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),CHAR(32),CHAR(1),3))-1),CHAR(32),CHAR(1),1))))
```

Here is a table explaining each step of both:

[image: Formula tables]

Formulas in image by reference number

1) Removed "," and extra white space

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""),CHAR(32)," "))
```

2) Get date part without time

```
=LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""),CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B3,CHAR(32),CHAR(1),3))-1)
```

3) Position of first space " "

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B4,CHAR(32),CHAR(1),1))
```

4) Position of second space " "

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B4,CHAR(32),CHAR(1),2))
```

5) Month number

```
=MONTH(1&LEFT(B4,3))
```

6) Year

```
=RIGHT(B4,4)
```

7) Day

```
=MID(B4,4,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B4,CHAR(32),CHAR(1),2))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B4,CHAR(32),CHAR(1),1)))
```

8) Date from dateparts Y,M,D

```
=DATE(B8,B7,B9)
```

9)  Long formula already given above as second solution

10) Get string before second "," , then replace remaining "," with ""

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,FIND(", ",B2,FIND(", ",B2)+1)-1),",","")
```

11) Formula given at top as first solution with lots of assumptions

### **VBA:**

**Edit:**

@ Darren Bartrup-Cook has pointed out that CDate is more effective than I imagined and you can simply do:

```
 CDate(Replace(.Range("B2").Text, ",", ""))
```

This will preserve the Time element. I have covered removing the time element earlier in the answer if required. Or you can do

```
Int(CDate(Replace(.Range("B2").Text, ",", "")))
```

**Original text:**

With vba you can use the `Instr` or `Instrrev` functions instead of `Find` to locate the occurrence of a character within a string. `Find` is used with range objects rather than the string within when using VBA. Instr starts searching from the start of the string, and `InstrRev` from the end i.e. right to left. These means argument orders change. More info on this is given in the references.

The simple formula as vba code using `CDate` function as per answer you referenced.

```
Public Sub test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Debug.Print CDate(Left$(.Range("B2").Text, InStr(InStr(.Range("B2").Text, ", ") + 1, .Range("B2").Text, ", ") - 1))
    End With
End Sub
```

The above you could use in a loop over the range where you want to convert values.

Something like:

```
.Range("B2") = CDate(Left$(.Range("B2").Text, InStr(InStr(.Range("B2").Text, ", ") + 1, .Range("B2").Text, ", ") - 1))
```

**Or,**

You can convert this into a user defined function and call from within the worksheet:

```
Public Function GetDate(ByVal rng As Range)
    GetDate = CDate(Left$(rng.Text, InStr(InStr(rng.Text, ", ") + 1, rng.Text, ", ") - 1))
End Function
```

**Calling UDF in sheet**

[image: UDF]

Note you either format the cells  as Date format to get the correct formatting or change the function to:

```
GetDate = Format$(CDate(Left$(rng.Text, InStr(InStr(rng.Text, ", ") + 1, rng.Text, ", ") - 1)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

References:

1. [Instrrev](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instrrev-function)
2. [Instr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function)
3. [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178845(v=office.12).aspx)
4. [Substitute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766241.aspx)
5. [Char](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/char-function-bbd249c8-b36e-4a91-8017-1c133f9b837a)
6. [User Defined Functions UDF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749875.aspx)
7. [CDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions)

Comment: `CDATE` is pretty good at converting dates in VBA - no need for the left, right, mid bits.  Just remove the commas instead:  `GetDate = CDate(Replace(Target, ",", ""))`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you. I didn't realise it was that effective. Have updated. Cheers again.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state what you want to convert it to.

However, to extract a standard Excel DATE or TIME value from your string, merely replace the second comma with a space, and apply either the TIMEVALUE or DATEVALUE function to the result.

If you want to create a combined date/time stamp, apply the VALUE function, or a double unary, to the substituted string:

### DATE/TIME

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ",2))  or
=--(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ",2)) 

Result -->   43195.41667 which can be formatted however you want
```

### DATE ONLY

```
 =DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ",2))
```

### TIME ONLY

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ",2))
```